# Name: "self" is not defined in model

Tags: python, tensorflow, forecasting

I am using tfr module for time series forecasting and have defined a model for training like below" -

```
#Train Model
best_model = tfr.tfr_models.Simple_Transformer.train( self = ,
                         train_dataset=trainset,   
                         test_dataset=testset,
                         loss_function='QuantileLoss_Weighted(quantiles=[0.6])',         
                         metric='MSE',
                         learning_rate=0.0001,
                         max_epochs=2,
                         min_epochs=1,
                         train_steps_per_epoch=10,
                         test_steps_per_epoch=5,
                         patience=2,
                         weighted_training=True,
                         model_prefix='test_models\tfr_model',
                         logdir='test_logs')
```

I ma not sure what to pass in self argument?

Comment: What does `self = ,` mean here? That argument shouldn't be there. `self` is an implicit argument when called.

Comment: I was not including in initial script but then it gave error that:                          
TypeError: Simple_Transformer.train() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'                    Hence included it but have no idea afterwards

Comment: try some `()` after `Simple_Transformer`. That will initialize a Simple_Transformer object that can then potentially run the `train()` method. However, you may find that `Simple_Transformer()` requires some arguments of its own...

Comment: this would raise a `SyntaxError`. please always provide a [mcve]. If you  are getting an error, please provide **the full error message including the stack trace**

Comment: Replace `self =` with `self` and then check.

Comment: @Raktim I tried this but giving error  name 'self' is not defined

Comment: @scotscotmcc I tried that also but it also not solving the issue

Answer (score 1):

The error you mentioned in the comments indicates you haven't created an object yet and are calling the method before doing so. To fix it, first create an object and then call the train method on the object.

Try something that looks more like: `best_model = tfr.tfr_models.Simple_Transformer().train(...)`